# Use mwl-confirm directive only onBlur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have everything working for this besides the onBlur.  All I need is for the mwl-confirm to be triggered by the ng-change. I am a bit new to angular and any help is appreciated.  Thanks. [mwl-confirm webpage](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-confirm#documentation)

```
<textarea rows="4" ng-model="resource.resources"
ngModelOnblur ng-change="call function or something to use mwl-confirm here?"></textarea>
```

This is what the mwl code would be.

```
mwl-confirm
         title="Save Changes"
         message="{{ _T('Are you sure you want save your changes?') }}"
         confirm-text="Yes"
         cancel-text="{{No}}"
         placement="left"
         on-confirm="myfunction(passIt);"
         confirm-button-type="danger"
         cancel-button-type="default"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to add a handler to your textarea using [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

And after it.
do a cick trigger on your button inside of the function where you handle blur

```
 $timeout(function() {
            angular.element(document.querySelector('#confirm_btn')).triggerHandler('click');
        }, 100);
```